# Serializing complex objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, serialization

I would like to know if there are any libraries or tools that can serialize complex javascript objects to a string (that may contain functions, regex, etc.) that don't require the use of npm.

I've come across several different libraries for this purpose but they all required npm.

Are there any good serialization libraries that don't require npm and are preferably written in pure vanilla JS?

Comment: Most npm libraries are also available on github, so you could clone the project from there, or are you looking for a cdn? What format do you want to serialize to?

Comment: @CharlesBamford A cdn would be nice. I want to serialize to a string.

Comment: Presumably you want a string, but do you want a json string, xml, csv, or some other format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npm is just a catalog of all of these pure vanilla js libraries.  You do not have to use npm to access them.  The packages will usually have a link to the source code on github or something.  Go to the source, clone the project, do whatever you need to.

Comment: How about for https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialize-javascript as an example?

Comment: Here is the file: https://github.com/yahoo/serialize-javascript/blob/master/index.js

Comment: There is nothing that says you can only use it via npm. It is open source

Comment: That script appears to have dependencies (ex: `require('randombytes');` near the very beginning).

Comment: It also has an additional dependency on safe-buffer from randombytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in JSON.stringify() for a vanilla, no external dependencies, object parser.

Comment: JSON.stringify() will not work for regex as an example. `JSON.stringify({a:/test/}) ` will not work. I am looking for a serializer I can serialize my complex objects to as a string, then deserialize back as an object. It does not have to be in a certain format.